# What does the というように in this sentence mean?

Tags: grammar

お月さまは一日一日とまるくなって、もうきょうは満月の日です。キキが旅立とうと決めた日がきたのです。お日さまがすこし西へかたむきかけたころから、キキは、コキリさんのつくってくれた新しい黒い服を着て、鏡の前で前をむいたりうしろをむいたり、大さわぎです。足もとでは黒猫のジジも負けてはいられない**というように**、横から鏡をのぞきこんでは、体をのばしたり、ちぢめたりしています。

I may have figured out it means "as if to say etc.." but im not entirely sure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct.

- と: quotation marker (負けてはいられない is the quote part)
- 言う: "to say"
- ように: "like"; "as if"

> 足もとでは黒猫のジジも負けてはいられないというように、横から鏡をのぞきこんでは、体をのばしたり、ちぢめたりしています。
>
> At her feet, Jiji the black cat, **as if saying "I won't be outdone"**, is peering into the mirror from the side, stretching and shrinking his body.